# Why does delaying handling of promise rejections sometimes result in UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning?

Tags: node.js, async-await, promise, unhandled-promise-rejection

When I run the following code, why do I get unhandled promise rejection warning?

```js
async function load() {
  throw new Error('error');
}

async function main() {
  const promise = load();

  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));

  try {
    await promise;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('caught error', e);
  }
}

main();
```

This is the output:

```
jkim@dev-jkim test $ node index.js
(node:25276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: error
```

Since `await promise` is around a try-catch, I'm confused why my try-catch isn't catching the error. I guess it's something to do with the `setTimeout` since the following code works:

```js
async function load() {
  throw new Error('error');
}

async function main() {
  const promise = load();
  try {
    await promise;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('caught error', e);
  }
}

main();
```

```
jkim@dev-jkim test $ node index.js
caught error Error: error
```

What is going on here? If promise rejections are not handled by the end of the current tick, does it automatically result in a unhandled promise rejection warning?

(I'm on node v10.16.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If promise rejections are not handled by the end of the current tick, does it automatically result in a unhandled promise rejection warning?

Yes. A Promise *must* have a rejection handler attached to it at the moment it rejects, or the rejection will count as unhandled. If you attach the rejection handler later, such as after a

```
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
```

the `load` Promise has rejected by the time the interpreter gets to the

```
try {
  await promise;
} catch (e) {
```

so, although the rejection can be caught with `.catch`, it wasn't caught by anything *at the moment of rejection*, resulting in the warning.

Best practice for this sort of thing is to always attach a rejection handler immediately - whether that means `.catch`, or inside a `try`/`catch`, or a `Promise.all`, or returning the Promise for the caller to handle.

Answer (score 0):

The function `load()` throws an `Error`. When an error is `thrown` while a `Promise` is being handled, the **`Promise` is rejected**. Now, if the Error `load()` threw is not caught then, a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` is thrown by JS

A better Illustration of your code is:

```
function load() {
    console.log("hello after some time");
}

const foo = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 5000);
})
.then(() => { load(); })
.catch((e) => { console.log(`Caught Error: ${e}`)});
```